# Outlook Auto Complete only emails from a certain domain

Tags: email, outlook

Is there any way to configure outlook to only auto complete internal emails or from a specific domain?  For example, I only want emails from gmail.com to show up in my auto complete list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not out of the box.

But you can certainly modify the nicknames list programmatically, either by loading the list using MAPI (it is stored in the `IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete` hidden message in the Inbox) or using Redemption (I am its author) - [RDONicknames](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdonicknames.htm) collection returned by [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) / [RDOPstStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOPstStore) / [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).**GetNickNames** methods.